# How to deserialize an array of primary keys with Django Rest Framework PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I followed the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) when setting up my serializer.

```
class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    songs = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Song.objects.all(), many=True, allow_empty=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'songs', 'created_at']
```

If I add a few songs to the playlist in the django admin and send a get request, I get the result I want.

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "teszt3",
    "songs": [
        351,
        350
    ],
    "created_at": "2022-01-14T14:04:36.238350Z"
}
```

But I want to create or update a playlist with a similar list of primary keys of songs. If I send a POST request with this body:

```
{
    "name": "test2",
    "songs": [350, 351]
}
```

I get this error:

```
Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str
```

If there's only one number (primary key) in the songs field, it works, but I want to create playlists with many songs at once. Is there a way to parse that array, or how could I solve this?

Edit:
models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    lyrics = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    verses = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True, default='')

class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
```

views.py

```
class SongViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Song.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = SongSerializer

class PlaylistViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Playlist.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = PlaylistSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some error in your models or endpoint. Since you didn't provided that info, here is a working example that is fully compatible with your Serializer.

models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    pass


class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
class CreatePlaylist(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PlaylistSerializer
```

Comment: I edited the original post with my code for these files and they're similar only I'm using Viewsets

Comment: I tried your code and it works, idk how are you getting this error. I tried from browser and test, both cases work.

Comment: I gave up and wrote the views for myself, only using the REST framework for serializing, not deserializing. This backend is for a React app by the way, and I started the new feature with writing the backend, so I only now started implementing it in React. Before I was using postman to mock the requests, and it turns out that was where I went wrong. I sent the request body as Formdata, not raw json...

Comment: The react app has been sending json requests before as well (to the Song endpoints) so now when I got Bad Requests again I realized something was wrong. (Since I was testing with postman, I built the new views expecting formdata)
Anyway, the point is you couldn't have known the issue, since I never talked about that part because I didn't think there could be a problem there. If anyone else has a similar problem, make sure that your requests are sent as raw json if you're working with Django REST Framework.